# Sinatra / Ruby: access set variable from Model

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have defined some variables:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  set :public_folder, relative('public')
  set :views, relative('views')
```

I tried to access them from my Model both with

```
options.public_folder
```

and

```
settings.public_folder
```

Neither of them seem to exist within the scope of the Model. How can I access them else?

Comment: Where is the method `relative` defined? Shouldn't `set :views, './views'` be enough?

Comment: Where's your model? Does your model know anything about the `App` class?

Comment: Have you tried placing them in a `configure do ... end` block?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
…
  configure do
    set :public_folder, File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "public"))
    set :root, File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  end
…
end
```

And here is an example how to access this settings in views. In my case this is HAML:

```
%p= settings.public_folder
%p= settings.root
```

And page shows:

```
/Users/sashaegorov/Development/ruby/rvs/public
/Users/sashaegorov/Development/ruby/rvs
```

Which are correct paths in my system.

**Note:** `File.expand_path()` works very well, it always helps to get real path to file or folder. **__*FILE*__** is also useful here.